# Keras LSTM loss is NaN and acc 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to train an LSTM network, but the loss is always `NaN`. My data is scaled between 0 and 1 so I don't think exploding gradients are an issue. What could be causing this issue?

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict as dd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.losses import SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)

data = pd.read_csv(r"D:\ML_Datasets\Signal\Myo\s1\data.csv")
EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 16
MAX_LEN = 1000

samples_dict = dd(lambda: {})

def normalize(v): # Scale to [0, 1]
    norm = (v - np.min(v))/np.ptp(v)
    return norm

def get_repetition(y):
    samples_dict[str(y.loc[y.index[0], "stimulus"])][str(y.loc[y.index[0], "repetition"])] = y.iloc[:, 2:].to_numpy()

def get_stimulus(x):
    if x.loc[x.index[0], "stimulus"] == 0:
        return
    x.groupby("repetition").apply(get_repetition)

data.groupby("stimulus").apply(get_stimulus)

X = []
Y = []

for stim in samples_dict.keys():
    for rep in samples_dict[stim].keys():
        vals = np.array(samples_dict[stim][rep])
        vals = normalize(vals)
        pad = np.zeros(shape=(MAX_LEN - vals.shape[0], 16))
        X.append(np.concatenate((vals, pad), axis=0))
        Y.append(int(stim))

X = np.array(X) #(72, 1000, 16)
Y = np.array(Y) #(72,)

print(np.min(X), np.max(X))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=X[0].shape))
model.add(Dense(12, activation="softmax"))

optimizer = optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

# fit model
history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Comment: It is an exploding gradient issue (nothing to do with input scaling), as you have sequences with 1000 timesteps, the gradients are exploding.

Comment: Why does 1000 timesteps imply exploding gradients?

Comment: A recurrent network applies the same function over and over, and the number of timesteps is how many times this function is applied, so the longer the timesteps, more chances of gradients exploding

Comment: @Harry Stuart - Did you try adding a Dense hidden layer with relu as activation.